# onmouseover not working with absolute postion

Tags: javascript, css, absolute, onmouseover

Everything in this code works just fine until I position my absolute element to the top then `onmouseover` doesn't want to work at all. I tried using CSS `:hover` and that did the same thing.

```html
<html>
        <div class="stylewrap">
          <div class="style">
            <h3 class="stylesub"><span id="letterF" onmouseover="change1()">F</span></h3>
          </div>
        </div> 
 </html>
        
 <style>
     .stylewrap {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
     } 
     .style {
        position: relative;
        color: blue;
     }
 </style>
            
            
 <script>
       function change1(){
          document.getElementById('letterF').style.color="red";
       }
 </script>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear on what is the incorrect output. Please add more detail

Comment: when I mouse over the letter f, the color does not change. If i take out the code : top:0 it works just fine

Comment: I have updated the question with a code snippet. It works

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any `onmouseover` event with normal css it can be achieved

```css
.stylewrap{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   } 
   .style{
   position: relative;
   color: blue;
       }
       
.AbsoluteHover:hover{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="stylewrap">
   <div class="style">
      <h3 class="stylesub"><span id="letterF" class="AbsoluteHover">Test Hover</span></h3>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I figured it out. I had to set my z-index to 10. Thank you all for the help :)